# SQL Average calculating reverse

Tags: sql

Im trying to calculate a window average, every 5 minutes with some timestamps and values.
This is the data:

| timestamp | value |
| --- | --- |
| 2021-02-20 08:30:00.0000000 | -511.48129 |
| 2021-02-20 08:29:00.0000000 | -506.36255 |
| 2021-02-20 08:28:00.0000000 | -495.60007 |
| 2021-02-20 08:27:00.0000000 | -492.71252 |
| 2021-02-20 08:26:00.0000000 | -493.10629 |
| 2021-02-20 08:25:00.0000000 | -481.03131 |
| 2021-02-20 08:24:00.0000000 | -489.82510 |
| 2021-02-20 08:23:00.0000000 | -485.49384 |
| 2021-02-20 08:22:00.0000000 | -480.76880 |
| 2021-02-20 08:21:00.0000000 | -476.83130 |
| 2021-02-20 08:20:00.0000000 | -488.77502 |
| 2021-02-20 08:19:00.0000000 | -481.03137 |
| 2021-02-20 08:18:00.0000000 | -477.35629 |
| 2021-02-20 08:17:00.0000000 | -467.51254 |
| 2021-02-20 08:16:00.0000000 | -457.40631 |
| 2021-02-20 08:15:00.0000000 | -447.56262 |
| 2021-02-20 08:14:00.0000000 | -456.09381 |
| 2021-02-20 08:13:00.0000000 | -447.16879 |
| 2021-02-20 08:12:00.0000000 | -442.18134 |
| 2021-02-20 08:11:00.0000000 | -427.35007 |
| 2021-02-20 08:10:00.0000000 | -430.50012 |
| 2021-02-20 08:09:00.0000000 | -434.43756 |
| 2021-02-20 08:08:00.0000000 | -424.20004 |
| 2021-02-20 08:07:00.0000000 | -411.73135 |
| 2021-02-20 08:06:00.0000000 | -422.23135 |
| 2021-02-20 08:05:00.0000000 | -381.67505 |
| 2021-02-20 08:04:00.0000000 | -377.47507 |
| 2021-02-20 08:03:00.0000000 | -366.84381 |
| 2021-02-20 08:02:00.0000000 | -387.58130 |
| 2021-02-20 08:01:00.0000000 | -388.76260 |
| 2021-02-20 08:00:00.0000000 | -385.74377 |

I use this query to calculate averages:

```
SELECT  DATEADD(MINUTE, DATEDIFF(MINUTE, 0, [timestamp]) / 5*5, 0) AS [date_truncated], AVG(CAST([value] AS NUMERIC(10,1))) AS [average_value] FROM OPENQUERY ("HISTORIAN", 'SELECT * FROM ihRawData

WHERE rowcount = 0 

AND samplingmode = RawbyTime

AND TimeStamp BETWEEN ''2021-02-20 08:00:00'' AND ''2021-02-20 08:30:00''

AND Quality LIKE Good*

AND TagName LIKE "VB02_D01_W01_BF0X_PV.F_CV"

order by timestamp descending'
)
GROUP BY DATEDIFF(MINUTE, 0, [timestamp])/5
ORDER BY [date_truncated] DESC
```

Then i get these results:

| date_truncated | average_value |
| --- | --- |
| 2021-02-20 08:30:00.000 | -511.500000 |
| 2021-02-20 08:25:00.000 | -493.760000 |
| 2021-02-20 08:20:00.000 | -484.340000 |
| 2021-02-20 08:15:00.000 | -466.180000 |
| 2021-02-20 08:10:00.000 | -440.680000 |
| 2021-02-20 08:05:00.000 | -414.840000 |
| 2021-02-20 08:00:00.000 | -381.280000 |

The problem is that the average value at `2021-02-20 08:00:00.000` is calculated from
`2021-02-20 08:00` to `2021-02-20 08:05`

So it uses the values:

`-381.67505`

`-377.47507`

`-366.84381`

`-387.5813`

`-388.7626`

`-385.74377`

I want the result set data to start at 2021-02-20 08:05 and have the value `-381.280000`

Any help is appreciated

Comment: There is no chance that is your actual query. It is full of syntax errors. And posting images of data is nearly useless. https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors-when-asking-a-question#:~:text=Images%20are%20harder%20to%20read,actual%20code%20and%20formatting%20it.

Comment: Images of data doesn't help us either; if you want to supply sample data ideally do so as DDL and DML statements, or *at least* as well formatted tabular `text` or a markdown table.

Comment: This doesn't appear to be SQL Server.  [GE Historian](https://www.ge.com/digital/applications/proficy-historian) perhaps?

Comment: Yes its using a linked server, to a GE Historian. I made a mistake when copying the SQL Query. Have updated it now.